# Distortion in view when ionic1 app is build for android platform

Tags: ionic-framework

I have developed an app before 2 years using Ionic1. When I am adding platform to this application and building it for android, view is getting distorted but everything is fine when this application is build for ios.

I am attaching the screenshot of the screen in both (IOS/Android).

Android
[image]

IOS (Ipad)
[image]

Have a look at the list in both the device.

Any guidance will be helpful for me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note each is actually rendering in a different browser ie safari vs chrome, and while they should use the same underlying webkit, there are differences.

So basically - your fix is in css, I am sure you can recreate your android issue if you test using ionic-serve in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the instant response and as I am a naive developer in web so can you please elaborate

Comment: Thanks IonicBurger I have resolved this issue by modifying my css files.